# need to know switch size for a 4 coil electric stove burner

Tags: electrical

i have burners that are 1500 watt (4 coils) and need to match the switch to the burner. i have seen a 5.2 to 6.5 amp infinite sw on eBay? will that work thanks

Comment: Do you have a model number for the stove?

Comment: If you don’t know the wattage go bigger. A smaller switch could go up in smoke where a larger one can handle the wattage.

Comment: It's not possible to say if the switch you're considering will work, with the limited information you gave.